# Free invalid pointer error

Tags: c++, opencv

I have the following for loop:

```
for (size_t matchIdx = 0; matchIdx < matcherTypes.size(); matchIdx++)
{
  std::vector< DMatchVector > matches12;
  std::vector< DMatchVector > matches21;
  try
  {
    poi.knnMatch(descriptorsInterior, descriptorsCar, cfg.getPOIMatchKNN(),
                 matcherTypes[matchIdx], matches21);
    poi.knnMatch(descriptorsCar, descriptorsInterior, cfg.getPOIMatchKNN(),
                 matcherTypes[matchIdx], matches12);
  }
  catch (MyPOIException& mpoie)
  {
    std::cerr << mpoie.what() << std::endl;
  }

  DMatchVector matches;
  filterDMatch(matches12, matches21, matches);

  ElectPOI elPOI;
  std::vector< size_t > cntrVec(matches.size(), 0);
  elPOI.counterPOIs(matches, cntrVec);

  KeyPointVector filteredKPs;
  elPOI.thresholdKeyPoints(1, kpInteriorVec, cntrVec, filteredKPs);

  std::cout << "keypoints found:   " << kpInteriorVec.size() << std::endl
            << "keypoints matched: " << matches.size() << std::endl;


  cv::Mat tmpMat;
  cv::drawKeypoints(interiorImage, filteredKPs, tmpMat);
  cv::imshow("filtered keypoints", tmpMat);
  cv::waitKey();

} // for each matcher type
```

I have no pointers, except for OpenCV `Ptr` in `knnMatch(...)` method of `poi` (that is defined outside the for loop):

```
void POI::knnMatch(const cv::Mat& queryDescriptorsIn, const cv::Mat& trainDescriptorsIn,
                   int knnIn, const std::string& matcherTypeIn,
                   std::vector< DMatchVector >& matchesOut)
{
  std::vector<DMatchVector> result;

  cv::Ptr< cv::DescriptorMatcher > descriptorMatcher
                                          = cv::DescriptorMatcher::create(matcherTypeIn);
  if (descriptorMatcher.empty())
  {
    std::string msg = "Matcher of type " + matcherTypeIn + " was not created!";
    throw MyPOIException(msg);
  }
  descriptorMatcher->knnMatch(queryDescriptorsIn, trainDescriptorsIn, result, knnIn);

  matchesOut = result;
}
```

I do not understand why does it crash with the following error:

```
*** Error in `/home/me/projects/prj/build/prj': free(): invalid pointer: 0x000000000110dda2 ***
```

In fact it crashes every second step of the loop before displaying the image. Any sugestions? What am I doing wrong?

---

**EDIT**

Valgrind says:

```
==10329== Invalid read of size 8
==10329==    at 0x605479: ElectPOI::counterPOIs(std::vector<cv::DMatch, std::allocator<cv::DMatch> > const&, std::vector<unsigned long, std::allocator<unsigned long> >&) (CElectPOI.cpp:12)
==10329==    by 0x5D8A87: main (main.cpp:199)
==10329==  Address 0xc74ec60 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd

valgrind: m_mallocfree.c:303 (get_bszB_as_is): Assertion 'bszB_lo == bszB_hi' failed.
valgrind: Heap block lo/hi size mismatch: lo = 449, hi = 450.
This is probably caused by your program erroneously writing past the
end of a heap block and corrupting heap metadata.  If you fix any
invalid writes reported by Memcheck, this assertion failure will
probably go away.  Please try that before reporting this as a bug.
```

The function is like this:

```
void ElectPOI::counterPOIs(const DMatchVector& matchesIn, std::vector< size_t >& cntrVecInOut)
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i < matchesIn.size(); i++)
  {
    int qryIdx = matchesIn[i].queryIdx;    
    cntrVecInOut[qryIdx]++;  // line 12
  }
}
```

Comment: In which line of the code you pasted does your error occur?

Comment: Your code is likely writing past the boundaries of an object or otherwise corrupting memory somewhere.  Try using a tool like valgrind to help find the problem.

Comment: I have mentioned it: "In fact it crashes every second step of the loop before displaying the image", but it is not an exact line. At the end of the second iteration of the for loop. PS I have edited the question

Comment: What call stack does a debugger show on crash?

Comment: @thedarksideofthemoon - The most likely place I think is when the `cv:ptr` auto deletes the wrapped descriptor object. However can you please add logging (even a simple console out) to test which area of code is causing the issue (or the issue is manifesting in at least).

Comment: I have added the problem found by `Valgrind`, and added the mentioned function. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Dennis I have added a few more info of what Valgrind says, does it means anything to you? Thanks

Comment: @thedarksideofthemoon `int qryIdx = matchesIn[i].queryIdx; cntrVecInOut[qryIdx]++;` Is `qryIdx` within bounds of the vector? Why are you not ensuring that this is the case?  I could see this easily being a number that is not within bounds of the vector.

Comment: @thedarksideofthemoon - It does indeed means something. It is very likely that Paul's comment above is accurate. You should use the `at` member of the `std::vector` class instead when you are not sure of the bounds, but are confident that this will not be an issue. If you are very unsure of the bounds then you should manually check the parameter to see if index is within the bounds.

Comment: The problem was the out of range of the index (`qryIdx`), Thanks all